# Should return type be explicitly specified when returning number?

Tags: java, performance

Consider some method returning `double`. In some cases I need to return the default zero value. I can explicitly specify it as `return 0d`, but java allows us to specify it as `return 0` with automatic casting.

Does this kind of casting happening at compile time or at runtime? Are there any potentially negative consequences from not specifying types (e.g. performance)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's called a [widening primitive conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2). There's no reason to use `0d` over `0`: it's a [constant expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28), so the compiler converts it to `0d` automatically.

If you look at the bytecode for returning `0` vs returning `0d`:

```
double a() { return 0; }
double b() { return 0d; }
```

You can see it's exactly the same:

```
  double a();
    Code:
       0: dconst_0
       1: dreturn

  double b();
    Code:
       0: dconst_0
       1: dreturn
```

so there cannot be any performance difference.